# Scraping Amazon using BeautifulSoup on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project that requires me to scrape product titles/names from Amazon using AWS Lambda. My code is as follows:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import requests
import base64


def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"}
    URL = "https://www.amazon.in/Amazon-Brand-Solimo-Foliage-Bedsheet/dp/B076ZTSW47/ref=sr_1_6_mod_primary_lightning_deal?dchild=1&pd_rd_r=53f449ad-419e-466d-bab8-2a09a026efc6&pd_rd_w=5XoS9&pd_rd_wg=VXhi2&pf_rd_p=d848f904-cfb3-4815-b7b2-fe0f44e4153f&pf_rd_r=B9HGM8VTCBCPSTBNW5Z6&qid=1616001168&refinements=p_n_format_browse-bin%3A19560802031&s=kitchen&sbo=Tc8eqSFhUl4VwMzbE4fw%2Fw%3D%3D&smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&sr=1-6"

    content = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'}).string.strip()

    return {
         'title' : title,
     }
```

For some reason, this is only working when my URL is from Amazon.in (India) but not amazon.com (US) * Note: I am not in India (unsure if that plays a role in anything)

If I keep all the rest same and simply change the URL to something from amazon.com (US). When I inspected both the .in and US pages, both had a span element with the id 'productTitle'
for example:

```
URL = https://www.amazon.com/Saucony-Mens-Kinvara-Running-Shoe/dp/B07Q8Y4GQL/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=c0VM8&pf_rd_p=de0c3fe6-321f-473e-bef6-6a700af423d3&pf_rd_r=S7482G8JKWVS6GB5ADG8&pd_rd_r=faa67bb1-ca9b-4c1d-a730-21c49cfd9b35&pd_rd_wg=KiSz4&ref_=pd_gw_trq_rep_sims_gw
```

I am getting this error:

```
Response
{
 "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'",
 "errorType": "AttributeError",
 "stackTrace": [
   [
     "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
     14,
     "lambda_handler",
     "title = soup.find(\"span\", attrs={\"id\":'productTitle'}).string.strip()"
   ]
 ]
```

}

I am pretty sure this has something to do with the User-Agent and Amazon disallowing scraping. I am very new to web-scraping so please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if there are any other changes to make. The code I have is incredibly simple so I am pretty sure the error is with the headers/User Agent but once again, I am very new to this and need some direction on it

**EDIT: @MendelG [suggested an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66678913/12349734) that actually worked on other IDEs such as Pycharm or Spyder, but it is still giving the same error on AWS Lambda, Does anybody know the reason lambda is executing it differently?**

Comment: I find it amusing that you're scraping Amazon with their own service, but that's unrelated. :) What's related is that they're blocking your scrapper if it hits `.com` or `.de`. So, I guess you'd be better of sticking to `.in`.

Comment: The issue is that it needs to be used on amazon.com (in the US)

Comment: I think they would like you to use the Amazon Product API rather than scraping the website.

Comment: Where can i find the Amazon Product API?

Comment: I can only find the Advertisement API but nothing for products

Answer (score 0):

Add `"upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"` to your `headers`:

```
headers = {
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0",
}
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0",
}

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Saucony-Mens-Kinvara-Running-Shoe/dp/B07Q8Y4GQL/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=c0VM8&pf_rd_p=de0c3fe6-321f-473e-bef6-6a700af423d3&pf_rd_r=S7482G8JKWVS6GB5ADG8&pd_rd_r=faa67bb1-ca9b-4c1d-a730-21c49cfd9b35&pd_rd_wg=KiSz4&ref_=pd_gw_trq_rep_sims_gw"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "productTitle"}).string.strip())
```

Output:

```
Saucony Men's Kinvara 10 Running Shoe
```

Comment: this is not working for me. I am getting the exact same error

Comment: @AdministrativeLab0284 Interesting. I added my full code, see if that works if you copy it.

Comment: hmm seems to be working on PyCharm but not AWS Lambda

Comment: @AdministrativeLab0284 I'm not sure how to further help. Wait for other answers.

Comment: Has this run properly for you in lambda?

Comment: @AdministrativeLab0284 I haven't tried. I don't use it.